# how can i do code conversion from PHP function to Java function

Tags: java, php

This is the Java code for the function which create a keyed hash digest, and I want to do the same but in PHP code.

Java code:

```
private String generateHash(final InputStream is, final int iteration,final String key) throws IOException,NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeyException {

                Mac sha256_HMAC;

                sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

                final SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);

                sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

                byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];

                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {

                            sha256_HMAC.update(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }
                byte[] digestValue = sha256_HMAC.doFinal();

                 for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {

                            sha256_HMAC.reset();

                            digestValue = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(digestValue);

                }

                return Base64.encodeBase64String(digestValue);
    }
```

This the PHP code I have tried, but the output of both code are not same.

And also that I think I'm missing something somewhere because I don't know alternative for each code statement of Java in PHP:

```
 function generateHash($file, $iteration, $key){
                        //$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', 'hello, world!', 'mykey');

                        $inithash=hash_init('SHA256',1,$key);

                        //mb_strlen($string, '8bit')

                        while ($buffer=fread($file,"2048")) {
                            hash_update($inithash, $buffer);
                        }

                        $hash = hash_final($inithash);
                        $hashbyte = unpack('C*',$hash);
                        for($i=0;$i<$iteration;$i++)
                        {
                            //unset($hashbyte);
                            $inithash=hash_init('SHA256');
                            $inithash = hash_final($inithash);

                        }

                        return base64_encode($inithash);
                    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: i have updated the php code which i tried , please have look at it once.

Comment: You noticed that you're not actually using the `$hash` or the `$hashbyte` values in your loop, haven't you?

Comment: yes , i know but i dont know that how to use that because they hash_final() accepts only one param. which is hash_init() output. and there is where i m confused .

Comment: Well, you need to use a hash_update before the hash_final. It's not exactly like Java.

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha Did you solved it ?